# "undefined reference to" errors when compiling in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I tried compiling a sample from: http://equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html#forget. I adjusted it a bit not to use arguments. There was also a type conversion error which I fixed.

I am left with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include </usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include </usr/include/alsa/pcm.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int i;
        int err;
        short buf[128];
        snd_pcm_t *capture_handle;
        snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hw_params;

        const char dev[] = "test";
        if ((err = snd_pcm_open (&capture_handle, dev, SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot open audio device %s (%s)\n",
                 dev,
                 snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc (&hw_params)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot allocate hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
                 snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any (capture_handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot initialize hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
                 snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access (capture_handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot set access type (%s)\n",
                 snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format (capture_handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot set sample format (%s)\n",
                 snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near (capture_handle, hw_params, (unsigned int*)44100, 0)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot set sample rate (%s)\n",
                 snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels (capture_handle, hw_params, 2)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot set channel count (%s)\n",
                 snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params (capture_handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot set parameters (%s)\n",
                 snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        snd_pcm_hw_params_free (hw_params);

        if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (capture_handle)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot prepare audio interface for use (%s)\n",
                 snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            if ((err = snd_pcm_readi (capture_handle, buf, 128)) != 128) {
                fprintf (stderr, "read from audio interface failed (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
                exit (1);
            }
        }

        snd_pcm_close (capture_handle);
        exit (0);
}
```

When compiling it with: `gcc main.cpp -o alsatest -lasound -lstdc++` it works like a charm, but when compiling it wit qt i get:

[image: errors]

I wouldn't be even trying this but I want to have it running in qt so I can build a cross-platform app (after also adding support for WASAPI).

**EDIT:**

found solution: add LIBS += -lasound in .pro file

Comment: Did you add `-lasound` in QT creator?

Answer (score 1):

`-lasound` tells the linker to pull in the asound library so that your snd_*() function calls will resolve. You probably didn't specify asound in the QT IDE.